# Nagios doesn't execute external commands even though they are shown in the logs

Tags: nagios

I want to use SNMP traps and to do so I need the external nagios commands to be executed.

I already checked the config:

```
check_external_commands=1
command_check_interval=-1
```

The command file is accessable.

When I send an external command to nagios, the command is shown in the logs, but it seems it isn't executed. So I tried to set the result of a passive check in the web interface (submit passive check result...). The log shows:

```
[1484062350] EXTERNAL COMMAND: PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;server11;RAID-Array;1;Testing|
```

Nothing happens.

The service definition:

```
define service {
name                            SNMP_TRAP
service_description             SNMP_TRAP
active_checks_enabled           1       ; Active service checks are enabled
passive_checks_enabled          1       ; Passive service checks are enabled/accepted
parallelize_check               1       ; Active service checks should be parallelized
process_perf_data               0
obsess_over_service             0       ; We should obsess over this service (if necessary)
check_freshness                 0       ; Default is to NOT check service 'freshness'
notifications_enabled           1       ; Service notifications are enabled
event_handler_enabled           1       ; Service event handler is enabled
flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
check_command                   check-host-alive      ; This will be used to reset the service to "OK"
is_volatile                     1
check_period                    24x7
max_check_attempts              1
normal_check_interval           1
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           120
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,u,c,r
#contact_groups                  netops-24x7       ; Modify this to match your Nagios contact group definitions
register                        0
}

define service {
use             SNMP_TRAP
host_name               server11
service_description RAID-Array
check_interval      120 ; Don't clear for 2 hours
}
```

Comment: can you show the service def for "RAID-Array"?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file which contain all externals commands which must be executed by nagios :

```
tail -f /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
```

Moreover, you can test locally your command if you write directly in this file with the following syntax :

```
echo [timestamp] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;server11;RAID-Array;1;Testing >> /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
```

Be sure:

- the timestamp you send to nagios is ths same date of your server.
- the name of your host,
- the name of your service and this service is
  declared in your host

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I double checked the timestamp, hostname and service name. Since the commands from the web interface are shown, I think everything must be correct. The log shows the command, but there is no result.

Comment: have you tried to write directly in the file nagios.cmd ?

Comment: I have a sript which writes directly to nagios.cmd. The log file shows the external command, but no state change.